# Listable compiled functions used in NMinimize

Tags: list-manipulation, mathematical-optimization, compile

This is an example from MMA:

```
cListable = Compile[{x}, (x-1)^2, RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}]
```

In case of single entry:

```
cListable[ 10.1]
```

Returns:

```
 82.81
```

and if we give it a list:

```
 cListable[ {-5, 0, 5}]
```

Returns:

```
 {36., 1., 16.}
```

Is it possible to use cListable, or any other compiled function, in `NMinimize` so that the function I want to minimize take a list as its argument and as a result use all of my CPU cores to minimize the function? The point of doing this is using all the CPU cores available and reduce the computation time.

Comment: Ok, I have not tested this, but in theory this should be possible without any additional hassle. At least when using certain optimization algorithms that only rely on evaluating the objective function directly.

Comment: @yashar I am not sure if any of the optimization algorithms used by `NMinimize` take lists as arguments (1.e. parallelize the optimization process). My understanding is that they evaluate the variable combinations in series. @Daniel Lichtblau can confirm this.